# How to reset the USB Mode selection after accidentally selecting 'Always' instead of 'Just Once'?

Tags: settings, usb-connection-mode, lg

I have an LG-H700. When I plug it in to a computer it typically would should a pop-up asking which type of USB connection mode I want to use. This pop-up would have two buttons "Always" and "Just Once" along with a list of modes including charging and MTP. But not including anything like "Always Ask".

I accidentally clicked on the always button once and now I can't figure out how to get it to reset back to asking every time the device is plugged in.

How do I clear the default USB mode setting so that it will ask each time the device is plugged in?'

Comment: Usually there is an option in the Android Developer settings for changing the default USB mode.

Comment: @Robert There is `Select USB Configuration` in there. When I click it I get a pop-up with all of the various types and a cancel button. But there is no setting for "always ask" or anything like that. And when I change this setting it seems to be only temporary until the device is unplugged / re-plugged. The entry in the notification bar on the other hand does save if I choose always again. Though I trying to get it back to asking every time.

Comment: Try revoking USB authorization and then connect again. Maybe you get that option back

Comment: @beeshyams gave it a shot clearing the authorizations and then reconnecting but still it won't show the dialog on plug in any more.